# Can I call a get_list within a exp:stash:set and use conditionals + single variables?

Tags: matrix, stash, conditionals

I've got an interesting problem that is leading me to believe I am approaching things totally wrong with stash... Essentially I am trying to call a "get_list" inside a variable that I am using as a placeholder in the layout.

Here is what I am trying to do:

I have a layout that I share across the site

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{stash:embed:partials:global_html}
  <head>
    {stash:embed:partials:global_html_head}
  </head>
  <body class="{stash:body_class}">
    <div class='container shadow'>
      <header class='header-page' role='banner'>
        {stash:embed:partials:global_html_header}
      </header>
      <!-- /END #Header -->
      <section class='content' role='main'>
        {!-- Define the primary content or listing in the model. --}
        {if {exp:stash:not_empty name="content-primary"}}
          <article class='content-main'>
            {exp:stash:content-primary}
          </article>
          <!-- /END .content-main -->
        {/if}
      </section>
      <!-- /END section .content -->
      <section class='sidebar-page' role='complementary'>
        <h3>Sidebarpaloooooza</h3>
      </section>
      <!-- /END .sidebar-page -->
    </div>
    <!-- /END .container -->
    <footer class='footer-page container' role='contentinfo'>
      {stash:embed:partials:global_html_footer}
    </footer>
  </body>
  <!-- /END .body_class -->
</html>
```

In the layout I have placeholder variables to grab data from my models for display in the layout:

```
{!-- Define the primary content or listing in the model. --}
{if {exp:stash:not_empty name="content-primary"}}
  <section class='content-main'>
    {exp:stash:content-primary}
  </section>
  <!-- /END .content-main -->
{/if}
</section>
<!-- /END section .content -->
```

In my model I am grabbing a nested list of entries

```
{exp:stash:set_list
  name="listing"
  parse_tags="yes"
  parse_depth="2"
}
  {exp:channel:entries
    channel="ch_company_location"
    dynamic="no"
    {global:param_disable_default}
  }
      {stash:some_var}{cf_var_goes_here}{/stash:some_var}
      {!-- This is a Matrix Field --}
      {exp:stash:set_list:nested name="employees"}
        {cf_matrix_field}
          {stash:var_one}{cf_var_1}{/stash:var_one}
          {stash:var_two}{cf_var_2}{/stash:var_two}
          {stash:var_three}{cf_var_3}{/stash:var_three}
        {/cf_matrix_field}
      {/exp:stash:set_list:nested}
  {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}
```

What I can't wrap my head around is how to get conditionals, {count}, {switch}, and {total_results} to work in when defining {exp:stash:content-primary}:

```
{!-- Primary content area --}
{exp:stash:set
  name="content-primary"
  output="no"
  parse_conditionals="yes"
  parse_tags="no"
  parse_vars="yes"
}
  {exp:stash:get_list
    name="listing"
    prefix ="parent"
  }
    {exp:stash:get_list:nested
      name="employees"
      prefix ="emp"
    }
      {if emp:count == 1}
        <div class="employees">
      {/if}
        <div class="employee {emp:switch="first||last"}">
          <dl>
            <dt>{var_one}</dt>
            <dd>{var_one}</dd>
            <dd>var_one</dd>
          </dl>
        </div>
      {if emp:count == emp:total_results}
        </div>
        <!-- /END .employees -->
      {/if}
    {/exp:stash:get_list:nested}
  {/exp:stash:get_list}
{/exp:stash:set}
```

No matter what I do I trigger the following errors:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in /system/expressionengine/libraries/Functions.php(683) : eval()'d code on line 9
```

or

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Use of undefined constant count - assumed 'count'
Filename: libraries/Functions.php(683) : eval()'d code
Line Number: 9
```

I've tried parent:switch/parent:count/parent:total_results and just plain old {switch}/{count}/{total_results} in addition to the "emp:*" to no avail.

Am I approaching this incorrectly? Is there a way to define global "buckets" that I can load stash variables, lists, and nested lists into inside my layout(s)?

I'm using:

- EE 2.5.5
- Matrix 2.5.5
- Stash 2.3.6

Comment: Doesn't `parse_tags` need to be `yes` in your `{exp:stash:set name='content-primary'}` ?

Comment: I've tried it both ways with no luck but Mr. Croxton sent me a reply on twitter that I'll try out when I get to office here in a bit.

Comment: @JasonVarga I figured it out! I'll post he answer here shortly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some help from the wonderful Mr. Croxton I was able to sort it out. Here is how to pull this off.

When grabbing the data in your model you need to stash the {entry_id} of the parent list (I call mine {e_id} for no real reason). Then, when setting the nested list, provide context with the {entry_id} by using name="employees_{entry_id}".

```
{exp:stash:set_list
  name="listing"
  parse_tags="yes"
  parse_depth="2"
}
  {exp:channel:entries
    channel="ch_company_location"
    dynamic="no"
    {global:param_disable_default}
  }
      {stash:e_id}{entry_id}{/stash:e_id}
      {stash:some_var}{cf_var_goes_here}{/stash:some_var}
      {!-- This is a Matrix Field --}
      {exp:stash:set_list:nested name="employees_{entry_id}"}
        {cf_matrix_field}
          {stash:var_one}{cf_var_1}{/stash:var_one}
          {stash:var_two}{cf_var_2}{/stash:var_two}
          {stash:var_three}{cf_var_3}{/stash:var_three}
        {/cf_matrix_field}
      {/exp:stash:set_list:nested}
  {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}
```

When getting the list you need to add a prefix to your lists (parent and nested) so that {count}, {switch}, and {total_results} work as intended. You also need to provide the nested list context using the stashed entry_id from the parent list. {e_id} in this case:

```
{!-- Set the primary content area --}
{exp:stash:set
  name="content-primary"
  output="no"
  parse_conditionals="no"
  parse_tags="no"
  parse_vars="yes"
}
  {exp:stash:get_list
    name="listing"
    prefix ="employees"
  }
    {if employees:count == 1}
      <div class="employees">
    {/if}
    {exp:stash:get_list:nested
      name="employees_{e_id}"
      prefix ="employee"
    }
      <div class="employee {employee:switch="first||last"}">
        <dl>
          <dt>{var_one}</dt>
          <dd>{var_two}</dd>
          <dd>{var_three}</dd>
        </dl>
      </div>
    {/exp:stash:get_list:nested}
    {if employees:count == employees:total_results}
      </div>
      <!-- /END .employees -->
    {/if}
  {/exp:stash:get_list}
{/exp:stash:set}
```